# How do you extend a class with a jQuery wrapped set?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

The following almost works...

```
$el = ->
$el:: = $ '#test'
new class extends $el
  constructor: ->
    @append '<h1>Worked!</h1>'


    # this will overflow the stack
    @find('[role=test2]').append '<h2>Also Worked!</h2>'
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/66a3jdot/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was staring me in the face...

```
new class
  @:: = $ '#test'
  constructor: ->
    @append '<h1>Worked!</h1>'
    @find('[role=test2]').append '<h2>Also Worked!</h2>'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wycleffsean/66a3jdot/2/